# Why do I keep getting undefined when using clientx and clienty property?

Tags: javascript

```
var box=document.getElementById("box");
var display=document.getElementById("display");/*to display clientX result*/
var x=box.clientX;

box.addEventListener("click", show);

function show(){
    display.innerHTML=x;
}
```

I feek like there is something simple going over my head that I just cant see

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: What is the expected behavior? showing the `box`'s `x` clicked position on `display`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the x-position of the mouse-click inside the box-element, you can achieve this with the help of the properties provided by the click-event.

```
let box = document.getElementById("box");
let display = document.getElementById("display");

function showMouseX(event){
    display.innerHTML = event.clientX;
}

box.addEventListener("click", showMouseX);
```

Answer (score 0):

The properties are `clientLeft` and `clientTop`, not `clientX` and `clientY`. See [the Element interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element). So

```
var x=box.clientLeft;
// -------------^^^^
```

---

Separately, and this may or may not be a problem depending on what you're doing, the line

```
var x=box.clientX;
```

gets the **value** of `clientX` from `box` as of when it runs, and then stores that *value*. There's no ongoing connection between `x` and `box.clientX`. So when the click occurs later and `show` is called, it shows the value as of *earlier*, when `var x=box.clientX;` ran. Depending on when that is, even if you make it `clientLeft`, you may get `0` instead of a valid value (if you're reading it during the initial loading of the page, and so the page may not have been laid out yet). Again, depending on what you're doing, you may want to wait and look up `box.clientLeft` when the click occurs. E.g.:

```
var box = document.getElementById("box");
var display = document.getElementById("display");

box.addEventListener("click", show);

function show(){
    display.innerHTML = box.clientLeft;
}
```

Comment: Maybe he thinks that `box.clientX` holds the MouseEvent's `clientX` property upon the click event on `box`? that's the only reasonable guess, to me.

Comment: @briosheje - Hard to say, it could go either way, though I tend to think it's just a simple naming error. Maybe worth your posting an answer in case that's what the OP meant?

Comment: Nah, let's see if that's what he needs, it was just to add something to your answer, which is already complete and likely what the user is looking for. I'm just wondering how he came up with `clientX` instead of `clientLeft` :P

Comment: @briosheje :-) Easy mistake to make.